# Connect via Proxy while using UTLS and HTTP 1.1 Request

Tags: http, go

I am trying to connect to a Host using Random TLS Fingerprinting. I am using https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls (see my issue i created on https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls/issues/42)

My issue is now, how can i utilize a HTTP or SOCKS5 Proxy while opening that connection?

The Code im using right now is:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "time"

    "github.com/refraction-networking/utls"
)


var (
    dialTimeout   = time.Duration(15) * time.Second
)

var requestHostname = "google.com"
var requestAddr = "172.217.22.110:443"


// this example generates a randomized fingeprint, then re-uses it in a follow-up connection
func HttpGetConsistentRandomized(hostname string, addr , uri string) (*http.Response, error) {
    config := tls.Config{ServerName: hostname}
    tcpConn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, dialTimeout)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("net.DialTimeout error: %+v", err)
    }
    uTlsConn := tls.UClient(tcpConn, &config, tls.HelloRandomized)
    defer uTlsConn.Close()
    err = uTlsConn.Handshake()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("uTlsConn.Handshake() error: %+v", err)
    }
    uTlsConn.Close()

    // At this point uTlsConn.ClientHelloID holds a seed that was used to generate
    // randomized fingerprint. Now we can establish second connection with same fp
    tcpConn2, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, dialTimeout)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("net.DialTimeout error: %+v", err)
    }
    uTlsConn2 := tls.UClient(tcpConn2, &config, uTlsConn.ClientHelloID)
    defer uTlsConn2.Close()
    err = uTlsConn2.Handshake()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("uTlsConn.Handshake() error: %+v", err)
    }

    return httpGetOverConn(uTlsConn2, uTlsConn2.HandshakeState.ServerHello.AlpnProtocol, uri)
}

func main() {
    var response *http.Response
    var err error

    response, err = HttpGetConsistentRandomized(requestHostname, requestAddr, "/2.0/ssocookie")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("#> HttpGetConsistentRandomized() failed: %+v\n", err)
    } else {
        //fmt.Printf("#> HttpGetConsistentRandomized() response: %+s\n", httputil.DumpResponse(response,true))
        dump, err := httputil.DumpResponse(response, true)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%+s\n", dump)
    }
    return
}

func httpGetOverConn(conn net.Conn, alpn string, uri string) (*http.Response, error) {

    req := &http.Request{
        Method: "GET",
        URL:    &url.URL{Host: "www." + requestHostname  + uri},
        Header: make(http.Header),
        Host:   "www." + requestHostname,
    }

        req.Proto = "HTTP/1.1"
        req.ProtoMajor = 1
        req.ProtoMinor = 1

        err := req.Write(conn)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(conn), req)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steffen said, you have to create a proxy dialer first, dial the proxy to create a net.Conn, then use that net.Conn when creating the uTLS Client, before handshaking. For brevity's sake, your custom dialTLS function would look something like:

```
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "net"
    "net/url"    

    "github.com/magisterquis/connectproxy"
    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
    utls "github.com/refraction-networking/utls"
)

var proxyString = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
                                                                          
dialTLS := func(network, addr string, _ *tls.Config) (net.Conn, error) {
    proxyURI, _ := url.Parse(proxyString)

    switch proxyURI.Scheme {                                                       
    case "socks5":                                                                 
            proxyDialer, err = proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", proxyString, nil, proxy.Direct)
    case "http":                                                          
            proxyDialer, err = connectproxy.New(proxyURI, proxy.Direct)            
    }   

    conn, err := proxyDialer.Dial("tcp", addr)
    uconn := utls.UClient(conn, cfg, &utls.HelloRandomizedALPN) 

    ...
}
```

Two suggestions:

1. Use the "connectproxy" module referenced above if you intend to tunnel through a HTTP CONNECT proxy.
2. Make life easier for yourself and take a look at the [Meek pluggable transport source](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/tree/meek-client?id=70c28e34dca7125895921c4161033666148dc3f0) for Tor. There's a 'utls.go' module which takes care of everything for you, including setting up either a http or http2 transport depending on the negotiated ALPN protocol. It only supports SOCKS but you could easily adapt it to handle HTTP proxies.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP proxy and SOCKS proxy work be having some initial proxy specific handshake after the TCP connect. After this handshake is done they provide a normal TCP socket which then can be used for doing the TLS handshake etc. Thus, all you need is to replace your

> ```
> tcpConn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, dialTimeout)
> ```

with a proxy specific method to setup the TCP connection. This can be done by using [SOCKS5](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy#SOCKS5) in `x/net/proxy` to create the appropriate Dialer or similar using the HTTP CONNECT method is done in [connectproxy](https://godoc.org/github.com/magisterquis/connectproxy).

Comment: Thanks. So this is what my code now looks like, though nothing happens anymore.


`//tcpConn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, dialTimeout)
 urll, err := url.Parse("https://127.0.0.1:8080")
 prox, err := connectproxy.NewWithConfig(
  urll,
  proxy.Direct,
  &connectproxy.Config{
   ServerName: requestHostname,
  },
 )
 if nil != err{
  panic(err)
 }
 tcpConn, err := prox.Dial("tcp", addr)
 if err != nil {
  return nil, fmt.Errorf("net.DialTimeout error: %+v", err)
 }`

Comment: @NecronomiconCoding: I have no idea what you mean with *"...though nothing happens anymore"*. And I have no idea of what the actual requirements of your specific proxy are. Based on your code you seem to assume a HTTP proxy which itself is accessed by HTTPS. But most HTTP proxies are actually accessed by plain HTTP (and can still be used to proxy HTTPS traffic). So you might just access the proxy the wrong way - or not - impossible to say due to a lack of details from you.

Comment: I am using it in combination with mitmproxy (SSL Certificate is installed). Mitmproxylog shows: "127.0.0.1:53557: clientconnect". The issue is the code is not being completely ran anymore. Before my code from the first post was showing the Server response. Now i am not getting any response or similar.

Comment: @NecronomiconCoding: likely the proxy need to be accessed by HTTP and not HTTPS as you are doing. Since you are doing it wrong it cannot do a a proper proxy handshake with the proxy, i.e. proxy expects a HTTP CONNECT request while your code starts with a TLS handshake.

Comment: Thanks, when accessing it via HTTP it gives me the error failed: malformed HTTP response: http2_handshake_failed

Comment: @NecronomiconCoding: I have no idea where exactly you get this error  - please be aware that I neither can see your current code nor can I read your mind nor do I have a way to reproduce anything what you are doing.