# How would I use an HTTP proxy when using a custom DialTLS Function in the transport

Tags: http, go, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to use a custom DialTLS Function in the http.Transport whilst using a HTTP proxy at the same time.

This is what I tried so far but whenever I configure the HTTP proxy it doesn't use the custom DialTLS Function :

```
    tr, err := NewTransport("771,4865-4866-4867-49196-49195-49188-49187-49162-49161-52393-49200-49199-49192-49191-49172-49171-52392-157-156-61-60-53-47-49160-49170-10,65281-0-23-13-5-18-16-11-51-45-43-10-21,29-23-24-25,0")
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }
    tr.Proxy = http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)
    tr.DisableKeepAlives = true
    httpclient := &http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: 2 * time.Second}
    proxyURL, err := url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", "127.0.0.1:80"))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("invalid proxy")
    }
```

I have looked into the docs for the http.Transport and I found nothing that can help. Incase this is also required this is the custom DialTLS function I'm using:

```
    dialtls := func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        dialConn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        config.ServerName = strings.Split(addr, ":")[0]

        uTLSConn := tls.UClient(dialConn, config, tls.HelloCustom)
        if err := uTLSConn.ApplyPreset(spec); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if err := uTLSConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return uTLSConn, nil
    }
```

I'm trying to change the ja3 fingerprint a.k.a tls config. If anyone knows how I could achieve this please let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624954/connect-via-proxy-while-using-utls-and-http-1-1-request/64282413#64282413

Comment: hey @wahman51 did you figure out a solution for this problem? I'm trying to solve the same task - changing the TLS fingerprint + use the proxy. Did you end up with a solution in Go or did you use something else to solve this task?